# Configure cors for specific api url

Tags: nginx

I made an API point that I want to access outside the main domain. When testing a request in jsfiddle, it gives the error Access-Control-Allow-Credentials. After that I tried adding a new section **location /wp-json/app/v2/post**. With these settings I get 404

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    # SSL configuration goes here
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://varnish;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
    }

    location /wp-json/app/v2/post {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
}
```

If copy the proxy settings to the **location /wp-json/app/v2/post {** section, then the error is: **'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values**

How to configure Nginx so that the request to **/wp-json/app/v2/post** passes without errors